# How can I practice javascript

Tags: software-development

I want to improve myself by practicing in web software (javascript), but I don't know how to do it or where to find it

I don't have any project idea in my head.Is there a website that offers projects that I need to develop?

I would appreciate if you help me hopefully the problem has been sufficiently descriptive

Answer (score 1):

[Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/) is a great place to start looking for ideas on anything web(front end) related as well as [Github](https://github.com/) for(front end & back end) project ideas.

**Free Resources** 
- [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/)
- [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/)
- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/)

**Paid Resources** 
- [Javascript and Jquery - Book](http://javascriptbook.com/about/)
- [Javascript Pocket Reference - Book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920011460.do)
- [Accelerated Javascript Training - Udemy](https://www.udemy.com/javascript-bootcamp-2016/)

Comment: hundreds just a google/duckduckgo/bing away - https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/